# Modify default registration form in Django-registration-redux

Tags: python, django, django-registration

How do I add a custom field in the default registration of django-registration-redux ?

Also how do I disable the "verification-by-email" feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend the parent User class.

Here is an example where two new fields have been added:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required.Links Userprofile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    # Override th __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

For more check [this link](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/login_redux.html)

For registration without verification you should use The “simple” (one-step) backend and include following link in your project url.py file:

```
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
```

for more details see [here](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/simple-backend.html?highlight=registration.backends.simple.urls).